# Python, EOF binary

Tags: python, binary, eof

I'm trying to read a file in python as binary.
Im interested in four bytes at a time, however I seem to be stuck in the infamous while loop:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
      while file:
            file.read(4)

print "EOF"
```

I've been trying this for the past hour, I never reach the end of the file, even in tiny text files. I did a "print test = file.read(4)" only to see that it prints ""

How can I make sure it stops? My first idea was to make a if statement saying if file.read(4) (in a variable) == ""{4} or something, but this might actually appear in a file, right? so it could potentially stop in the middle of it.

Is the only other option to beforehand calculate the size of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the file, `file.read(..)` will return an bytes (or string depending on your python version):

Check the return value of the `file.read`; break if it's empty:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    while True:  # --> replaced `file` with `True` to be clear
        data = file.read(4)
        if not data:  # empty => EOF
        # OR   if len(data) < 4: if you don't want last incomplete chunk
            break
        # process data
```

Comment: `file` will never be `Falsy`. `while file` whould be `while True`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Thank you for the pointing. I update the code accordingly. BTW, even before the change, the code should work because of `if ... break`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

`file` is an _io.BufferReader object, not `None`, so never be treated as `False`.

You should check if the return value of `file.read(4)` is an empty string(treated as False).

Comment: there's no `File` object, but you're kind of right. Please enhance your post a little so I can upvote :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh, I see. It is _io.BufferReader, thanks.

Comment: in python 3, yes. In python 2 it's `file`. The wording is bad, though: `list` is an object, and can be treated as "falsy" when empty. Same for empty string. That's not the real reason. The reason is that the file object has a type that _cannot_ be "falsy" when the file is fully read, unlike C++ pattern

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're right. Just being `object` is not the reason. You know what I intended though :)